# Flex 4.1: <mx:List> had rowCount properly for the limit the displayed items. <s:List> doesn't

Tags: apache-flex, list, flex4

Hi I'm using flex 4.1 to write an application.

i read in the documents that  has the rowCount property to set how many items to display. the  does not have that property.

how can I limit the list to display 3 items ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Flex 4 this is driven by the skin rather than the component itself.  You can create a custom List skin and in the VerticalLayout of the DataGroup, set the requestedRowCount to 3, then set the skin for your List to be your new custom skin.  To get started, just copy the default ListSkin into your custom skin file and make your changes.  Here's the relevant section from the default ListSkin file:

```
   <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <!--- The default layout is vertical and measures at least for 5 rows.  
            When switching to a different layout, HorizontalLayout for example,
            make sure to adjust the minWidth, minHeihgt sizes of the skin -->
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="5" />
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
```

Just remove requestedMinRowCount and replace it with requestedRowCount="3"  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

you can directly set `requestedMinRowCount` to 3 in the `VerticalLayout`

```
<s:List>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout requestedMinRowCount="3"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Comment: Right. There's no need to create a custom skin for this particular tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wade for the great answer, it put me on the right path.

Actually you don't need to copy the default skin, if it's only the row count you want to fix Just use the  tag inside the  tag to control the minimum row count like Wade described.